# jquery css not applied with angularjs routing

Tags: jquery-mobile, routes, angularjs

I wish to implement angularjs with jquery mobile all works fine except that the jquery mobile css is not applied.

It works when I don't use routing in angularjs but with routing, the css stops working.

What do I do? I also included the `jquery-mobile-angular-adapter` still it's not working.

Comment: Do you have an example?  Use http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:3662656 as a base

Answer (score 1):

"if you generate new markup client-side or load in content via Ajax and inject it into a page, you can trigger the create event to handle the auto-initialization for all the plugins contained within the new markup." - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

To solve this problem you have to tell JQuery to initialize all plugins after Angular loads the content, you can do this in your controller.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    $(document).trigger('create'); //$(document) or just the part that was loaded with ajax
});
```

I don't know jquery-mobile-angular-adapter, so I can't help with that.